# token.php returns usernamenotfound

Tags: php, moodle

I'm making an educational app where the user must login using moodle username and password and along with other stuff there will be moodle information.

The problem is that we found out that we can validate (and enable webservices access) through the token.php request. But the only thing that we get as a return is:

```
{
"error": "The username was not found in the database",
"stacktrace": "* line 179 of /login/token.php: moodle_exception thrown\n",
"debuginfo": "\nError code: usernamenotfound",
"reproductionlink": "http://#####.com/"
}
```

We trying changing the shortname, setting on .php file, but nothing seems to work.

So we need to know if there is anything we can do to fix it or we are possibly using the wrong function.

Just to note, the Moodle version we are using is the 2.3.1

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. It appeared to be that I had a password for the user containing non-alphanumerical characters. This caused a UTF-8 problem.

In the settings I changed the requirement that a password must contain 1 non-alphanumeric character, so I could give the webservice user a alphabetic password. token.php worked OKE after that.

Comment: I found my problem was very similar indeed! I was having problems converting from text to html encoding. After I made a switch to force the strings to use html encoding the token.php worked like a charm!